# Motive, Motivative, or Motivating?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, vocabulary, suffixes

What is the most fitting adjective to describe '(something) that motivates' among motive, motivative, and motivating?

EDIT:

Reading from the answers that 'motive' is not an adjective, actually I put that word in the list from my search in the Merriam-Webster's dictionary.

1. of or relating to motion or the causing of motion <motive energy>
2. moving or tending to move to action

Does this word have nothing to do with 'motivation'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Something that motivates you is a *motivator*.
- Something that actually moves something else is a *motive force*.  In this phrasing, "motive" is indeed an adjective.  However, the more common word for something that physically moves something else is *motor*.
- *motivation* originally referred to the act of putting something into *motion*,  but has taken on the connotation of encouragement or reason for action, rather than physical propulsion.
- And *motive*( the noun) has crowded out "motive" (the adjective,) while taking on pretty much the same connotation as *motivation*, to the point where asking "what were his motives?" is the same as asking "what was his motivation?".

So, if we need an adjective associated with these connotations, rather than with physical propulsion, the most apt would be "motivational".  There are scads of references, for example, to *motivational speakers* . . . while "motivative" in any context is barely a blip on the ngram graph.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=motivational+speaker%2C+motivative%2C+motive+force&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmotivational%20speaker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmotivative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmotive%20force%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

Motivational would be better than all three.  Of your list, motivating is the only one that fits.  Motive is not an adjective relating to motivation, and motivative is <s>not a</s> an awkward word.  Motive as an adjective relates to motion, but as a noun it is related to motivation.

Comment: I can find the word 'motivative' in at least two dictionaries online (Merriam-Websters and Random House (dictionary.com)). They list 'motivative' as a derived form of motivate and motivation, respectively). There is a list for the actual usage of this word here (http://www.thefreelibrary.com/_/search/Search.aspx?SearchBy=0&q=%22motivative%22&Search=Search&By=0)

Comment: I must have missed it in the m-w dictionary I checked.  I agree with dwjohnston that it is more awkward than motivating.

Answer (score 0):

Motive is a noun so doesn't fit.

> My motive for writing the paper was to make money.

*Motivative* is an awkward form, but is correct English apparently.

I can't see how it differs from *motivating*.

> The prospect of a holiday at the end of the year was very motivative.
>
> The prospect of a holiday at the end of the year was very motivating.
>
> The prospect of a holiday at the end of the year is very motivative.
>
> The prospect of a holiday at the end of the year is very motivating.